# PCB ribbon cable drop out easily

Tags: pcb

[image]

I have a PCB board and the ribbon cable keep drop out easily. I'm planing to find a way to solve it.

In my mind, I was thinking of:

1. Add in another connector (adaptor) with the locking type on top of the connector on the PCB board.
2. Replace the connector on the PCB. (I can not do it but the pin to pin distance is 2 mm)

Comment: How often is it disconnected? Maybe hot stick glue could help?

Comment: PCB = Printed Circuit Board.  PCB Board= printed circuit board board.  This message brought to you by the department of redundancies department.

Comment: Hi Winny, thanks for the adcise. I will take note on this option. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 2):

I would test both the connector in the PCB and that on the cable using another set of connectors of the same type to see which is responsible for easy drop out.

Answer (score 1):

Desoldering the connector may be best done with a hot air gun. But there is a risk of damage/accidental removal of other components.

A quick fix that doesn't involve heat would be to wrap some thin tape around the connector on the cable end. This will make the fit tighter, but still leaves you the option to easily unplug it later.

Answer (score 0):

I would say change the connector. Unsolder it and solder on a new one. Do the same thing on the cable.
It's most likely, that it's worn out or maybe even a bad product, that came like that from the company. Before you change both, you can check the fit of connectors first, so you won't do the Sizif's work.

Comment: The connector is not soldered to the flat cable, it is pressed to the cable, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insulation-displacement_connector).

Comment: @Uwe the proposal is to replace the PCB header *and* the IDC connector.  I'd do the IDC first though - it's both more likely to be worn, and far easier.